# How to print keys from a dictionary backwards

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary in which I want to read each individual key backwards until it reaches the underscore. Once it reaches the underscore, it should stop so I can set its item equal to a new variable.

I understand that I can use str.partition() to seperate at a certain character and that I can use [::-1] to read a string backwards, but I am not sure how to use them together with a dictionary.

```
    Payload_Values = {'Voltage_asleep(V)' : 10, 'Current_asleep(A)' : 5, 'Wattage_asleep' : 50}
    for c in (Payload_Values.keys())
        Payload_Values.partition(_)
```

Comment: I don't understand *it should stop so I can set its item equal to a new variable*. Do you mean you want to create a new string where the text after the underscore is replaced by some other text? If that's not it, can you give an example of what data you want to have before and after the change you're trying to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate a dict with `keys()` or `items()`, not `iteritems()`, in Python3 you need to convert these iterators to lists, otherwise it results an error if you add new element to the dict while iterating (I am just mentioning, this was ok in your example). Otherwise, you are close to the solution. I just do not understand completely, what do you want to do with the key? Print it? Take the part after the last underscore? Set a new key-value pair? Without knowing this, I am trying to present all combinations, please ask more specific if you need something else:

```
# this is because Python3 compatibility:
from __future__ import print_function
from future.utils import iteritems

for key, val in iteritems(Payload_Values):
    # new key is the part after the last underscore
    # or the whole string, if it does not contain underscore:
    new_key = key.split('_')[-1]

    # new key is the elements separated by `_`, reversed
    # and rearranged to a string:
    key_rev = '_'.join(key.split('_')[::-1])

    # new key is the complete string reversed:
    new_key = key[::-1]

    #
    # set a new element with the new key:
    Payload_Values[new_key] = 'your new value'

    # print the new key:
    print(new_key)

# if you want to modify the dict in this loop:
for key, val in list(Payload_Values.items()):
    # ...
    Payload_Values[some_key] = some_value
```

Comment: The new_key = key.split('_')[-1] is closest to what I was looking for. Unfortunately, it appears as though using that will strip my original key of the number value associated with it. Is there a way to keep the number assigned to it?

Comment: then you need to iterate with `iteritems`, I modified the example accordingly. in Python2 you have `dict.iteritems()`, but for Python3 compatibility, I show with iteritems from `future.utils`. this way you have the corresponding value for each key along the iteration (`val`) .

Comment: also if you want to modify the dict in the loop, you should chose the solution I just insterted to the bottom.